# cuda install for mask rcnn on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I'm working with mask rcnn. I need a gpu to do real time work. When I look at the system requirements for this, it wants cuda 10.0 (tensorflow-gpu=1.15) for this, I installed ubuntu 18.04 and after installing cuda 10.0, when I reboot, the screen freezes at user login. Can you help me to solve this problem?